# Is it possible to have a single line of a VBA script repeat "N" number of times?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm experimenting with recursive for the first time. In this problem, I have a huge dataset with many rows, and in each row, there's N number of 4 cell ranges to copy (from column O to column GB). I have the following function written:

```
Function Recursive(Rng As Range)

If N = 1 Then

Rng.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 670).Copy
Rng.Offset(1, -3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rng.Offset(, 6).Resize(, 4).Copy
Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Else
Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Repeat these two lines N times'

Rng.Offset(, 7 + 4 * N).Resize(, 3).Copy
Rng.Offset(N, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Recursive (N - 1)
End If
N = 0
End Function
```

I know it's pretty rough, and I see some problems already. Basically, if N is equal to 4, then I want the first two lines of the Else instruction to be repeated 4 times, then move on to carry out the next three lines over and over until N is equal to 1. Basically, where there are many ranges going across the dataset, I want to create a new line to put them into, including the cells to the left of Rng. Is it possible to put in a line where I've made my comment, that says "Go back and repeat these two lines N times?"

Comment: `if (...) then { loop ...}`, basically.

Comment: My answer was off the mark.  I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @MarcB's comment, there are many types of loops. I've chosen to do one main loop which reduces N by 1 until N = 0. Within that loop, if N = 1, then your special N = 1 code runs; otherwise if N = 4, it loops 4 times over that section of code, otherwise it runs your 'else' block of code.

```
Function Recursive(Rng As Range)

Dim OriginalN as Integer

OriginalN = N

While N <> 0

If N = 1 Then

    Rng.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 670).Copy
    Rng.Offset(1, -3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rng.Offset(, 6).Resize(, 4).Copy
    Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ElseIf N = OriginalN Then
    For x = 1 To OriginalN
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Repeat these two lines N times'
    Next x
Else
    Rng.Offset(, 7 + 4 * N).Resize(, 3).Copy
    Rng.Offset(N, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Recursive (N - 1)
End If

N = N - 1

Wend

End Function
```

You refer to 'going back' and redoing code, but using a GoTo statement is often considered sloppy if there are other methods available, as without proper care GoTo statements can run incorrectly/indefinately, and are somewhat harder to read.

Comment: Note that I wasn't quite clear on your instructions for when N = 4; I made it so that after running the 2 lines of code 4 times, it stops that IF statement and loops back again, without running the 3 lines of code until N loops back as 3. If you want those 3 lines of code to also run after the 2 lines have been repated, you will need to copy those 3 lines and put them aftger the FOR loop.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely in the right direction. Basically, N could be anywhere between 1 and 50. I just used 4 as an example of what I would want it to do in that case. I guess I could have a line that says `ElseIf N <> 1 Then` and replace 4 with N, wherever you have?

Comment: @user1996971 I'm not clear on what you're looking for, mathematically. The loop must have a consistent pattern to be able to set it like this. Do you mean that when N = the original value of N, you want those 2 lines of code run N times. Then, for each other value of N, decreasing by 1, you want the 3 lines of code run once, until N = 1, when you want those lines of code run? If yes, then you'll need to first define a new variable which = the original value of N; otherwise, N will always = N and it will always run the "N = 4" loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. I'd like those two lines to run N number of times, then have the other three lines run until N = 0, without running the first two lines again. I suppose I'll have to separate them, then. Any suggestions how?

Comment: @user1996971 See my edits above. It now does (I think) what you want mathematically but note that because of the recursion, if N = 20 at the outset, then N will equal OriginalN 20 different times (once each as it decreases down to 1).

Comment: Thanks man, I'm on the right track now. Seems like I'll have to post the rest of the macro and the context of the data tomorrow to get this to work smoothly. Thanks a lot!